# command:<mkdocs serve>error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: mkdocs

when I use this command `pip install mkdocs mkdocs-material`and `mkdocs serve`to run a simple project ,it throws an error`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`:

[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

**python** version is 3.8.5, **pip** version is`pip 21.1 from /home/linxianmiao/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

Comment: Did you able to resolve this issue?